# Convert list object to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with the following items :

```
poly = ['AddTicketResponse.xsd',     {
    'OrderServiceType': 'stPickUp',
    'Taxes': {'Tax': {'Caption2': None, 'Caption': 'Sales Tax IN',
              'Amount': '1.26'}},
    'CreditSubtotal': '0',
    'Version': '1',
    'NetSubtotal': '13.97',
    'CreatedTime': '2018-08-14T19:19:13Z',
    'PriceGroupName': '$$Regular Price Group$$',
    'PurchaseSubtotal': '13.97',
    'Status': 'tsOpen',
    'ItemCount': '2',
    'Seq': '105651',
    'Warnings': {'Warning': {'Message': 'The customer name from SpeedLine Connect differs from the name in the customer record.'
                 }},
    'PaymentTotal': '0',
    'Agent': None,
    'ID': '1678'
    'TaxSubtotal': '1.26',
    'MenuSelections': {'MenuSelection': [{
        'MenuCalculatedPriceOfAggregatedSelections': '0',
        'PLU': '44'
        }]}
    }]
```

Here Poly has two objects: 
I was Poly[1] which is :

```
{
    'OrderServiceType': 'stPickUp',
    'Taxes': {'Tax': {'Caption2': None, 'Caption': 'Sales Tax IN',
              'Amount': '1.26'}},
    'CreditSubtotal': '0',
    'Version': '1',
    'NetSubtotal': '13.97',
    'CreatedTime': '2018-08-14T19:19:13Z',
    'PriceGroupName': '$$Regular Price Group$$',
    'PurchaseSubtotal': '13.97',
    'Status': 'tsOpen',
    'ItemCount': '2',
    'Seq': '105651',
    'Warnings': {'Warning': {'Message': 'The customer name from SpeedLine Connect differs from the name in the customer record.'
                 }},
    'PaymentTotal': '0',
    'Agent': None,
    'ID': '1678'
    'TaxSubtotal': '1.26',
    'MenuSelections': {'MenuSelection': [{
        'MenuCalculatedPriceOfAggregatedSelections': '0',
        'PLU': '44'
        }]}
    }
```

to be a separate dictionary so that I can get all the values for 'MenuSelections' 
So far, I was just able to convert my xml file to the list and got those values.

```
root = ElementTree.XML(pos_xml)
xmldict = XmlDictConfig(root)
poly=[]
for key, value in xmldict.iteritems():
    poly.append(value)
```

Honestly, any suggestions will help.

Comment: It looks like `poly[1]` already is a `dict`. You can assign it to a new variable if you want `mydict = poly[1]` and then access the values like `mydict['MenuSelections']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = poly[1]
```

That will extract a reference to the dictionary in the second position of the `poly` list and store it in the new name `d`.

You can then use it to get what you want

```
print(d['MenuSelections']['MenuSelection'])
```

You can also index `poly[1]` directly:

```
print(poly[1]['MenuSelections']['MenuSelection'][0]['PLU'])
```

will print

```
44
```